# Good CMS for online books

Tags: open-source, cms, ebooks, books

I'm searching for a good Content Management System (CMS), which is appropriate for writing things like an online book.

## What I'm trying to achieve? What do I search?

Basically I would like to have a good and small CMS which can be used for writing content like a book. Which means, chapters with sub-chapters. Maybe sometimes with illustrations, maybe some kind of wide-screen photographic.

Each book should consists of an (ideally automatic generated) table of contents with a pagination for the chapters/sub-chapters.

It would be great if there is some kind of contribution possible, which means - people can correct/update typos, etc. But each of these changes should be reviewed by moderators before they will be published.

In addition to this, each book should be exportable to `.mobi` or `.pdf` for ebook readers too.

## Requirements (list)

- Ideally OpenSource
- Ideally for Linux based systems
- Ideally written in Ruby, Python, PHP or NodeJS
- Easy to use interface
- Not to bloated. I don't need a huge backend with API etc. etc. if it fits my current described needs. Every peace of software which is overhead can break or can be a security risk. Just software - no bloat-ware.
- Basic community features (*comments, maybe registration*)
- Workflow for reviews provided by the community (*non-administrative/non-moderation users*)

I'm sure that I'm not the first person who tries to achieve some kind of online open library at all. But if so, just let me know. Maybe I need to build something on my own. But normally I just don't want to re-invent the wheel over and over again.

Comment: I'm afraid Wordpress does not fit exactly in your requirements... I would recommend GetSimple CMS or Doku WIKI... good luck

Answer (score 1):

Personlly, I would use WordPress with an ebook plugin

**WordPress**

- OpenSource
- Runs on Linux
- Written in PHP
- Not bloated (unless you fill it up with plugins)
- Extremly easy to use interface
- Has a login and comments system built in
- Has a moderator section to moderate comments

Then I would buy this plugin (it's $33 and you get lifetime updates)

[image: Responsive FlipBook WordPress Plugin Logo]

[Responsive FlipBook WordPress Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/responsive-flipbook-wordpress-plugin/2372863)